# Is there a way to access Gmail's parsing of certain emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Gmail can automatically parse out certain emails, like tickets, orders, and bills. It shows the parsed out information as a card above the email. Is there a way to programmatically access that parsing, or to even check if an email was parsed in that way? Further, is the code Gmail uses to do that parsing open source or documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to [Highlights](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview#gmail_highlights) a form of Email Markup for Gmail. And yes you can mark up HTML formatted email to render these highlight cards. You can find official documentation linked below:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup